# How to start spring integraton java dsl subflows in Java 7?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

Hey i'm not able to get the sub flow part working with the java dsl.

```
public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
        .from("messageRoutingChannel")
        .route("headers." + HeaderKeys.CONNECTION_ID, new Consumer<RouterSpec<ExpressionEvaluatingRouter>>() {
            @Override
            public void accept(RouterSpec<ExpressionEvaluatingRouter> spec) {
                spec.subFlowMapping("connection101", 
                        IntegrationFlows.from("messageRoutingChannel")
                            .handle(new GenericHandler<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public Object handle(String payload, Map<String, Object> arg1) {
                                    System.out.println(payload + " after routing");
                                    return null;
                                }
                            })
                            .get());
            }
        })
        .get();
```

}

Now when i add an IntegrationFlow to a subflow i'll have to give it a `from()` right? I don't really know what to give there. I tried putting a `channel()` right on top of the `route()` and do a `from()` from that channel, but that didn't work either. Most of the examples in the reference use lambdas so there's no explicit `IntegrationFlows.from()` there. Just a `sf -> sf.handle()`

```
java @Bean public IntegrationFlow routeFlow() { return f -> f .<Integer, Boolean>route(p -> p % 2 == 0, m -> m.channelMapping("true", "evenChannel") .subFlowMapping("false", sf -> sf.<Integer>handle((p, h) -> p * 3))) .transform(Object::toString) .channel(c -> c.queue("oddChannel")); }
```

What does the from implicitly evaluate to though? How can i get it working in Java 7? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all it isn't good idea to to compose your own code that way with Java 7. Because it already looks like a plate of spaghetti. But what to do if you are going to add a business logic there?..

Fro your Java 7 case it would be better to use standard routing setting and make logic based on the channel and forget about sub-flows until Java 8 upgrade.

Anyway you can it like this:

```
spec.subFlowMapping("connection101", new IntegrationFlow() {

      @Override
      void configure(IntegrationFlowDefinition<?> flow) {
           flow.handle(...);
      }

})
```

Just because `sf -> sf.handle(...)` is a short form for an inline interface implementation.

Comment: Yeah it does look ugly I guess, but then I'm only gonna stick two outbound adapters in the sub flow so the business logic won't bloat it up much. I could make them into separate beans but they don't really have any potential of reuse. Plus the flow itself would be pointless if I have just the one router in it. Might as well make the router a bean and skip the dsl. I'll just separate it out and hope they okay java 8 soon here. Thanks!